# Excel Pivot Table add % Column when using Counts in Pivots

Tags: excel, pivot, percentage, calculated-columns

I have a data as follows:

```
Location      Responded
-----------------------
US            Yes
US            Yes
US
UK            Yes
UK            Yes
UK            Yes
```

I have run a pivot table and my pivot shows the following:

```
Location      Total     Responded
---------------------------------
US            3         2
UK            3         3
```

I have achieved this by adding a `Count of Location` to get the `Total` column and a `Count of Responded` to get the `Responded` column into the Pivot table.

I'm trying to then add a further column that would give me a `%`, with the output as follows:

```
Location      Total     Responded    Perc (%)
---------------------------------------------
US            3         2           66%
UK            3         3           100%
```

However, when I add a Calculated field (with the `function = Responded / Location`) I get a column with `#DIV/0!`'s.

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerPivot. Add your source table to the data model, then add the following measures:

```
NumberResponded:=CALCULATE ( 
    COUNTROWS('Source Table'),
    'Source Table'[Responded] = "Yes"
)

TotalResponded:=CALCULATE ( 
    COUNTROWS('Source Table'),
    ALL('Source Table'[Responded])
)

PercentResponded:=DIVIDE ( 
    [NumberResponded],
    [NumberTotal]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Responded] field to Values for a second time. Then right-click in the new column (Count of Responded) and select [Show Values as / %of]. Click OK. That should do the trick.